# Insert null into Sqlite from Python

Tags: python, json, sqlite

I have a table called 'test' that I'm creating through my Python code.

```
db = sqlite3.connect("mydb.db")
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test 
            (
                "id" text primary key,
                "field1" integer,
                "fiedl2" integer,
                "field3" text
            )'''
           )
```

I have a file where each line is a json. I read the file line by line and insert data from the json of each line into the table.

file.txt:

```
{'id':'abcde', 'field1': 10, 'field2': 20, 'field3': "hello"}
{'id':'asdf', 'field1': 20, 'field2': 5, 'field3': "world"}
{'id':'qwerty', 'field1': 1, 'field2': 2, 'field3': None}
```

If a field in the json doesn't have a value, I want to insert null into my sqlite table. So as in the last line above, if field3 doesn't have a value, I put None into it because this is what I read in other related questions.

However, when I insert as below:

```
for line in readfile:
    line = ast.literal_eval(line)
    columns = '", "'.join([i.strip() for i in line.keys()])
    columns = "\"" + columns + '\"' 
    placeholders = ', '.join('?' * len(line))
    sql = 'INSERT INTO test ({}) VALUES ({})'.format(columns, placeholders)
    cur.execute(sql, ["'" + str(i) + "'" for i in line.values()])
    db.commit()
```

I get 'None' instead of null when I perform a select statement from the Sqlite console.

```
sqlite> select * from test where id='qwerty' limit 1;
'qwerty'|1|2|'None'|
```

Can anyone please help me fix this? I'm using Python 3.4

Comment: Have you considered testing if a value is `None`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting a `"None"` string, because you're converting the `None` into a string before passing it to the `execute` function:

```
cur.execute(sql, ["'" + str(i) + "'" for i in line.values()])
```

So, as far as python/sqlite is concerned, you're inserting the string `"None"` - not the `None` object.

The point of having the parameters as second argument in the `execute` function is that it's supposed to do the value-to-sql-string representation for you. Hence, you should provide the values in their native python datatypes.

So, using

```
cur.execute(sql, list(line.values()))
```

should actually give you a `null` instead of `"None"`.

Comment: Works perfectly! I had to use cur.execute(sql, list(line.values()) though

Comment: Right - that's because you're using python3, where the values are returned as iterator - I missed that. I edited my answer accordingly.